# remember local administrator password on different user

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac

I have a roaming profile that is setup how I like, but was giving a Local Admin account on one computer. Each time it prompts for Admin PWD I have to type it in, is there anyway to store this so that it just uses those credentials every time?

This is on Windows 10

Comment: You may take the password off, or make it ""

Comment: Make one local Admin account and one password. Then just remember the one password. I do not recommend removing the password, and if just one, it is easy to remember.